# jpg Image brighter on Chrome than other browsers

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-3, google-chrome, safari

These are screenshots from chrome of a jpg image I added to my site. The css and html are the same and everything and I've been adding images the same way for years and have not had this problem. Why is this chrome image brighter than the safari image? And How do I fix it???

This is the chrome image

[image]

This is the safari image

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to the original image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome renders colors a bit differently. Here is the official report for it:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44872

Hope it helps you out.

Comment: Exporting the image to a png fixed the problem